# Different output in Ubuntu/Windows

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu

In this program:

```
char ** change_first(char string1[]){

    int len_string = strlen(string1);

    char string2[len_string];

    strncpy(string2,string1,len_string);

    string2[0] = 'h';

    char **array_string = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    if (!array_string)
        return NULL;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        array_string[i] = malloc(len_string + 1);
        if (!array_string[i]) {
            free (array_string);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    strncpy(array_string[0],string1,len_string);
    strncpy(array_string[1],string2,len_string);

    return array_string;
}

 int main(){
    char string[] = "Hello World!";
    char **res = change_first(string);

    printf("%s",res[0]);
    printf("%s",res[1]);

    free(res[0]);
    free(res[1]);
    free(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Windows output:

```
c:\VB\C\>cc -Wall -g test.c -o test

c:\VB\C>test
Hello World!n FiHAÏ!¶P
hello World!es(xàA┘Ý¶P
```

On Ubuntu:

```
VB@VB-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/C$ make test
cc -Wall    -g    test.c   -o test
VB@VB-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/C$ ./test
Hello World!
hello World!
```

Why windows is printing extra chars? And how can I fix this?

Running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits.
Virtual Box Running Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: You've got some of the random junk...

Comment: `strncpy(array_string[0],string1,len_string);array_string[0][len_string] = 0;` `array_string[1]` ditto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the problem

```
char string2[len_string];
```

change it to

```
char string2[1 + len_string];
```

you are not wrinting the terminating `'\0'`.

This is a quote from linux manual pages

> Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n  bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.